# How to return focus outline to button when click close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have 2 buttons and one layer(div) it can control show/hide.

I am trying to make them after click the close button which is in layer(div), 
the focus(outline) move to the button where I clicked before.

But I am stuck with jquery, I cannot figure it out which one is wrong.

This is what I tried so far, please help.

```js
$(function($) {

  $(".btn1, .btn2").on("click", function(){
    $(".layer").show().attr("tabindex","0").focus();;
  }); 
  $(".close").on("click", function(){
    $(".layer").hide();
    $(".btn1, .btn2").focus();
  }); 
  
});
```

```css
.btn1 { background:red}
.btn2 { background:blue}
.layer { display:none; margin:50px 0 0 0;  border:1px solid #000; background:gray }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">btn1</button>
<button class="btn2">btn2</button>
 
<div class="layer">
  layer
  <button class="close">close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to make them after click the close button which is in layer(div), the focus(outline) move to the button where I clicked before.

In the click handler for `.btn1` and `.btn2`, you can keep track of the most recently clicked button, and when the collapsible div is closed, you can simply focus on this most recently clicked button.

Here's the updated snippet:

```js
$(function($) {
  var previouslyClickedButton;
  $(".btn1, .btn2").on("click", function(){
    $(".layer").show().attr("tabindex","0").focus();;
    previouslyClickedButton = this;
  }); 
  $(".close").on("click", function(){
    $(".layer").hide();
    $(previouslyClickedButton).focus();
  }); 
  
});
```

```css
.btn1 { background:red}
.btn2 { background:blue}
.layer { display:none; margin:50px 0 0 0;  border:1px solid #000; background:gray }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">btn1</button>
<button class="btn2">btn2</button>
 
<div class="layer">
  layer
  <button class="close">close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try by using adding new class. Let see the below working exmple.

```js
$(function($) {

  $(".btn1, .btn2").on("click", function(){
  //instead of using body you can use any upper html element
    $('body').find('.setFocouss').removeClass("setFocouss");
    $(".layer").show().attr("tabindex","0").focus();
     $(this).addClass('setFocouss')

  }); 
  $(".close").on("click", function(){
    $(".layer").hide();
    $('.setFocouss').focus();
  }); 
  
});
```

```css
.btn1 { background:red}
.btn2 { background:blue}
.layer { display:none; margin:50px 0 0 0;  border:1px solid #000; background:gray }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">btn1</button>
<button class="btn2">btn2</button>


 
<div class="layer">
  layer
  <button class="close">close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the button which is clicked in a variable and then apply focus on that button.

```js
$(function($) {
  var btn;
  $(".btn1, .btn2").on("click", function(){
    btn=$(this);
    $(".layer").show().attr("tabindex","0").focus();;
  }); 
  $(".close").on("click", function(){
    $(".layer").hide();
    btn.focus();
  }); 
  
});
```

```css
.btn1 { background:red}
.btn2 { background:blue}
.layer { display:none; margin:50px 0 0 0;  border:1px solid #000; background:gray }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">btn1</button>
<button class="btn2">btn2</button>
 
<div class="layer">
  layer
  <button class="close">close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you I missed period before 'btn2'.  I just edit my code,  but the focus issue is still not solved